# @mui/x-date-pickers - Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/styles/alpha'

Tags: next.js, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I am getting this error in Next Js 14.0 for any component imported from @mui/x-date-pickers.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVNtp.png)

My package.json for mui:

```
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.15.5",
    "@mui/system": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.0.0-beta.0",
```

I tried to install `@mui/x-date-pickers@5.0.20` which an error for `@mui/material/util/unstableUser` and `@mui/x-date-pickers@6.0.19` which gives the same error as above.

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you find any solution? I think there's nothing like this version 6.0.19 is available for @mui/x-date-pickers package.